# Webbrowser control File Download dialog Bypass

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

Actually I want to download a file from website using Webbrowser Control, but because of File download Dialog box, I am not able to automate downloading process. For Bypass it I want to use webclient and need to transfer all session and cookies to webclient from WebBrowser Control or I need set all custom header from webbrowser control to WebClient.

Please Help me I am in very bad situation.

Thanks In Advance.....

Answer (score 1):

> Actually i want to download a file from website using Webbrowser
>   Control, but because of File download Dialog box, i am not able to
>   automate downloading process.

Implement a custom [Download Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Search the web for `IDownloadManager` and you'll find some samples in C#.

Comment: i am new to .net, i have tried but getting Exception while downloading, please can you provide sample solution which i can check properly or any link which contains working solution.

Comment: @Anand, this is as far as I can help: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSIEDownloadManager-8ab5d910