# How to download file from FileDownload popup using webBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

In my winform application i need to download file, the download process:

1. Click on download button.
2. web site popup File Download Window -> user can press (open/save/cancel)

but in background website process it's making a new frame with the file link in it's src attribute

What i need is to take the link and to send in to UrlDownloadToFile method

my code:

```
Browser.Document.GetElementById("downloadXls").InvokeMember("Click");
Application.DoEvents(); // freezes

HtmlWindow downloadFrame = Browser.Document.Window.Frames[2];
string downloadLink = downloadFrame.Document.Body.GetAttribute("src");
```

the issue that after i invoke `Application.DoEvents();` the process freeze and only continiue if i mannualy click on the File download window.

how can i pass the popup window and init the downloadLink.

One way i think i can handle it is by catching the window event and cancel it.

**What i tried:**

add new_window event by adding in the form designer:

```
this.webBrowser.NewWindow += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.webBrowser_NewWindow);
```

In Winform class:

```
private void webBrowser_NewWindow(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
   e.Cancel = true;
}
```

but File Downloader is not handle like a window, what else can be the answer ?

Thanks.

Comment: What'e the usage of `Application.DoEvents();`? Do you have an online sample site to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Processes all Windows messages currently in the message queue.

Comment: I know what the method perform ;) what's the usage here? Why you need to call it. And do you have an online url to use for test?

Comment: for invoking InvokeMember("Click");

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23380987/1768303) may help.